# Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId' or one of its dependencies on server, OK locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetopenauth

I have a page which compiles just fine and runs locally with Visual Studio, but throws a parser error when I publish it to the server. Here's the relevant code:

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" codefile="default.aspx.cs" codebehind="default.aspx.cs" inherits="WebApplication4._default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.UI" Namespace="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" TagPrefix="rp" %>
```

The error message, thrown on line 2, is "Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.UI' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." It goes on to provide this trace:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.UI
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.UI | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
```

Among the things I've checked:

- I'm targeting the correct .Net version for the IIS server I'm
  publishing to.
- The dotnetopenauth .dlls are, so far as I can tell, all present and
  accounted for in the /bin directory.
- There are no duplicate listings of dotnetopenauth libraries in my
  packages.config.

In case it matters, I'm running VS 2013, targeting .Net 4.

Comment: Can you check once if your `bin` folder specifically contains `DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.UI.dll` or not?

Comment: Yes, it contains that .dll.

Comment: Do your `bin` contains `Debug` or `Release` folders? If so, copy it there too and try once.

Comment: The bin folder doesn't have any subdirectories.

Comment: Try deleting all references to the .dll and readd it to the project.

Comment: Deleted and readded references; getting the same error when run on the server. Still works fine locally.

Comment: Found the problem. In IIS, the directory I was given to publish to wasn't set as an application. Once that was fixed, it worked just fine.